# All possible unique combinations of a set in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm building an app to test different icons. Admins upload a number of icons and input how many icons must be shown at the same time. The app then displays all possible sets of icons in sequence until all combination of icons have been shown.

Now, I need a function to generate all unique icons combinations based on two number:

- the number of total icons (i)
- the number of icons in each set (s)

If i = 6 and s = 3, I want the output to look as follows:

```
[
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 4],
  [1, 2, 5],
  [1, 2, 6],
  [1, 3, 4],
  [1, 3, 5],
  [1, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 5],
  [1, 4, 6],
  [1, 5, 6],
  [2, 3, 4],
  [2, 3, 5],
  [2, 3, 6],
  [2, 4, 5],
  [2, 4, 6],
  [2, 5, 6],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [3, 4, 6],
  [3, 5, 6],
  [4, 5, 6],    
]
```

Requirements:

- All sets have to be unique
- A number can only occur one time in a set

I have been trying to code a recursive function, but I havent anything really anything to show. I can't get my head around it :(

Comment: I think this pretty much answers your exact question: http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/51

Comment: Could you paste a code you have as far?

Comment: Link that @Jamiec shared is good. You can test here: http://experiments.mennovanslooten.nl/2007/combinator/combinator.html if you put 6 and 3 and press the button, you'll obtain the combination.

Comment: I won't treat this question as a javascript - its just a combination algorithm you are requesting. You can find it in Google

Comment: A recursive fn will blow the stack without trampolining for even modest data sets, but here you go http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off the idea given as an answer to this question:
[Computing all n-sized permutations without repetitions and without "classic" ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093289/computing-all-n-sized-permutations-without-repetitions-and-without-classic-ord)

> Then use C++ std::next_permutation like algorithms which work as
>   follows:
>
> - Go from left and find rightmost one preceeded by zero. Put one in
> - place of zero and sort the rest of array.

Disclaimer: My javascript is very, very rusty so I'm sure there is a much more elegant way of implementing this.

```
function combine(n, k) {
  var result = [];

  // initialize array of values
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    values[i - 1] = i;
  }

  // initialize permutations
  var perm = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i < k) {
      perm[i] = 1;
    } else {
      perm[i] = 0;
    }
  }
  perm.sort();

  whileloop:
    while (true) {
      // save subresult
      var subresult = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (perm[i] == 1) {
          subresult.push(values[i]);
        }
      }
      result.push(subresult);

      // get next permutation
      for (var i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (perm[i - 1] == 1) {
          continue;
        }
        if (perm[i] == 1) {
          perm[i - 1] = 1;
          perm[i] = 0;
          perm = perm.slice(0, i).concat(perm.slice(i).sort())
          continue whileloop;
        }
      }

      // no additional permutations exist
      break whileloop;
    }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining `n` elements in to number of sets with `k` elements each without repetitions, how to do it.
The algorithm is relatively simple, main idea: we consequently feed first set of `k` elements and then try to increment each element from the end of set to populate another *k-set* and so on.
When we can't do that we leave the process (all possible sets are ready).

```js
function combine(n,k) {
  var result = Array();
  var a = Array();

  // make initial (first) k-set
  for (var i=1; i<=k; i++) {
    a[i-1] = i;
  }

  j = k-1;
  while (j >= 1) {

    // submit current results
    result.push(a.slice());

    if (a[k-1] == n) {
      j = j - 1;
    } else {
      j = k-1;
    }

    if (j >= 1) {
      // make next k-set based on previous one
      for (var i=k; i>=j; i--) {
        a[i-1] = a[j-1] + i - j + 1;
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Note: JavaScript arrays have start index `0` so in code we have `-1` correction for array indices (cause set of possible values from `1` to `n`)

Comment: `combine(4,2)` produces 3 variants instead of 6